# SetAscending Business Central Sales Order List

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am attempting to use the SetAscending in Visual Studio Code for Business Central Sales Order List Page.  It works to set the Sales Order "No." field to descending however it does not reset the scrollbar to the top of the page.  I've tried adding it to multiple places and it sorts the page but no scrollbar update.  What code could I be missing?

Places I've added it to:
Sales Order List Page Extension - OnAfterGetRecord and OnAfterGetCurrRecord
Sales Order List Page Events -  OnOpenPageEvent, OnAfterGetRecordEvent, and OnAfterGetCurrRecordEvent

```
trigger OnAfterGetCurrRecord()
    begin
        rec.SetCurrentKey("Document Type", "No.");
        rec.SetAscending("No.", false);
    end
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must tell the page to navigate to the new first record.

In the OnOpenPage trigger you do the following:

```
Rec.SetCurrentKey("Document Type", "No.");
Rec.SetAscending("No.", false);
if Rec.FindSet() then; // use if-then to avoid error if there are no records within the filter
```

Comment: how would I write the part after FindSet(), I thought maybe then FindFirst but that seems to filter to only my very last record.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 methods to use as FIND

`FindFirst` = Find the first ocurrence of your filters

`Findlast` = Find the last ocurrence of your filters

`FindSet` = Find a set of ocurrence of your filter

You can use all of them with the `repeat` and `until` statements to loop through records.

The difference between `FindFirst` and `FindSet` for `Repeat` and `Until` is that `FindSet` find a Set of registers Whilst `FindFirst` find only one so `FindSet` it is more performant.

For your case
You need to modify the property sourceTableView. This is a page property. FindSet is used for variables not for DataSourceTable in page list.

Create a key in your table and then put this key in sourceTableView property of the page.

Comment: would you be able to provide sample code of how I would loop through the records to point the list page back to the top?  I understand the FindSet() but not sure what should be in then statement once it finds the set.

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: It is bad for performance to use a `repeat` with `FindFirst` or `FindLast` as they only retrieve a single record from the database. If you add a repeat afterwards it causes an extra roundtrip to the database. `FindSet` does the same as `FindFirst` meaning it finds the first record within the filter, but it also retrieves an additional number of records (the acutal number of records is optimized by the SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  Since, this is a standard list page in Business Central I could not modify the SourceTableView. I had to use two triggers to first sort and the move the cursor to the top of the list.

```
    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    begin
        rec.SetCurrentKey("Document Type", "No.");
        rec.SetAscending("No.", false);
    end;

    trigger OnOpenPage()
    begin
        rec.FindLast();
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was testing answers and reading about this subject on learn.microsoft.com, but the only trick that works is the following:

```pascal
    trigger OnOpenPage()
    begin
        Rec.SetCurrentKey(SystemCreatedAt);
        Rec.Ascending := false;
    end;
```

***Note:*** I'm sorting by a datetime object. But the clues are: `OnOpenPage` trigger, `SetCurrentKey` and `Ascending` property instead of `SetAscending`. This is the unique solution that leaves the scroll bar on the top, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

This also works, if you programatically open a page with Page.RUN:

```
procedure ShowYTDSalesOrders(DateFilter: Text)
var
    salesHeader: Record "Sales Header";        
begin
    salesHeader.RESET;
    salesHeader.SETRANGE("Document Type", salesHeader."Document Type"::Order);
    salesHeader.SetFilter("Order Date", DateFilter);
    salesHeader.SetCurrentKey("Order Date");
    salesHeader.Ascending(false);
    salesHeader.SetAscending("Order Date", false);
    if salesHeader.FindSet() then
        PAGE.RUN(PAGE::"Sales Order List", salesHeader);
end;
```